# how to store 'client_secret' and 'client_id' on Android app when using OAuth?

Tags: php, android, laravel, oauth

I am developing an android app for the existing website, so i developing login part to the an android app and  i use oAuth protocol.i have API for the users data and generate the `client_id` and the `client_secret_key` from the web site.so my question is.

- How to store this `client_id` and `client_secret` (in mobile app or any backed client web service)
- When i use backed client web app to store client id and secret how i authenticate users.

The web site built on the larevel php framework.

Comment: why dont you use string.xml to save the data?

Comment: no it's not secure way.. nowadays use backed web client to store data..but thing is i don't have proper idea about how it's work

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question use shared preferences. Shared Preferences allow you to save and retrieve data in the form of key,value pair.
Second question, read from the shared preference and send back the results to web server. Check if there is data present , and then get the value , validate it and transmit it accordingly. I recommend using this awesome library as a bonus to your questions.retrofit2.

Comment: thanks your help.i refer it..is that Shared preference is very secure method for store valuable data?..no any idea about using another back end client to store client id and other things.

Comment: what? i did not get that last part.

Comment: i mean store these data in a another web site and app communication with that web app and exchange the token..

Comment: did you consider using local-storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to securely save the id in the app you can use a Keystore.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

// get user password and file input stream
char[] password = getPassword();

java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
    ks.load(fis, password);
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html

Comment: @Michal thanks for your valuable comment i will refer it.is that very secure way to store data.any one can decode the apk and the can get file easy.no any idea about the using another back end web client ?

Comment: This is the same mechanism used to protect apps on the play store from impersonation. If it was not secure then it would be a serious problem. It is encrypted. Even if they have the keystore they still need the password. The password is not saved inside the app.